# add user to role with newest discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i'm using newest discord.js in node.js and i'm trying to add user to role, but it seems bot.addUserToRole() was removed.

How can I do it when I know only rank name, not it's ID?

Comment: I recommend asking on their official Discord server. https://discordapp.com/invite/bRCvFy9

Answer (score 18):

Here's what worked for me, hope this helps!

```
var role= member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role name");
member.roles.add(role);
```

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager) is the official documentation on it.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with:

```
var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "MyRole");
message.member.addRole(role);
```

Comment: I'm using the exact same code but it's not working. All I get is "TypeError: Supplied parameter was neither a Role nor a Snowflake." even though the `role. name` is true in the boolean loop function. I've console.log and it's null. I've allowed enabled manage roles and send messages. I just can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For me (right now) this works only:

```
var role = message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role name");
if (!role) return;
message.member.guild.roles.add(role);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, 2020, this Code works fine, and its easy to implement since its only based on the message object

```
let role = message.member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "your role");
if (role) message.guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.add(role);
```