# What does addRoles require as a member (to add the role to) Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Alright so I'm pretty new to the Discord.js environment but I've been looking and trying everything from everywhere but I always get the same errors for this and I don't really know why. Specifecally I'm having trouble with the .addRoles() block at the bottom of this code block, everything else works fine.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
if(reaction.emoji.name === "✅" && reaction.message.id === "697450986889019439") { //works
const guild = reaction.message.guild;
console.log(guild);

const memberWhoReacted = guild.members.cache.find(member => member.id === user.id);
console.log(memberWhoReacted);

var role = client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id === '697237754752532532').roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Patreon').id; // Overcomplicated way of retrieving id, I know lol
console.log(role);

memberWhoReacted.addRole(role);
  }
});
```

I have double-checked everything in this code block, The memberWhoReacted is correct (it returns the GuildMember as it should), the role returns the correct role object (I've also tried just hardcoding the id). everything is right! But the moment I put it together into .addRole() it all explodes.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: memberWhoReacted.addRole is not a function
//There's more console stuff I can share as well
```

I've honestly spent two days on this same problem (because I didn't want to bother anyone with this seemingly simple question) but I give up haha
Also, the my client is called *client* for sake of simplicity.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try `memberWhoReacted.roles.add(role)` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/61005930/535480

Comment: I think the answer I linked and its question covers the topic, but upvote that answer if it worked for you.  You can delete this question.