# Discord Bot how do I give a new user who enters the server a role automatically

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently writing a Discord bot that detects when a new member enters the server and automatically assigns them the "Guest" role.    What I found [add user to role with newest discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599732/add-user-to-role-with-newest-discord-js) . Only my question is in which method do I wrap this?
So how do I write the following, as proper code?

```
bot.on('new Member joint this server', role => {
   get the name of the member. give the role ('Guest')
})
```

My code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'token';

bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online')
});


// This happens only when someone writes, but is there also something like this when someone enters the             
// server for the first time?
// Discord Bot how do I give a new user who enters the server a role automatically

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.content === "Test") {
        msg.reply("Test back");
    }
})


var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "guest");
message.member.addRole(role);


bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [**guildMemberAdd**](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) Event.

You will need to enable the Guild Member intents on your Discord Developer Portal for this event.

[Learn about Intents Here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)

However the object passed in the event is the member that joined, not a role. You will have to define the role you want to add within the function.

The following is DJS **v12**

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
   const role = guildMember.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'guest');
   guildMember.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);

   console.log(`${guildMember.displayName} Has Joined The Server!`);
});
```